# Calculate limit: $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \Bigl(\frac{1}{\ln\bigl(\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+81}-8\bigr)}-18x\Bigr)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, logarithms

I have limit with fraction of 1 and natural logarithm of root in denominator and argument that substracted from the fraction.

I've tried to use some properties of logarithm, common denominator, product and divide denominator and use L'hopital rule after, but nothing seems to help.

thanks!

Comment: As written, that doesn't even seem to be well defined.  It looks like the inputs to your $\ln$ are negative?

Comment: But expression under the root always bigger than 8

Comment: @Alan:  I think the question is correct as it is written.  WolframAlpha gives a *well-defined* answer.

Comment: The question is entirely trivial. Just take limit for each term.

Comment: WolframAlpha uses the Laurent series expansion at $x=\infty$ to compute the limit to $\frac{5}{9}$

Comment: Ahh, I misread.  Never mind

Comment: Kavi but if I'll take it there will be $\infty-\infty$; @learning123 but I wondered is there any other solution

Comment: Using LHospital's rule, one can easily get the result.

Comment: @xpaul but how can I use it if it need $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ or $\frac{0}{0}$ and after finding derivatives I have $\infty$*something

Comment: @KirS, see the answer.

Comment: factor the 81 out of the square root, so the square root becomes of the form $\sqrt{1+x}$, which is easy by the binomial theorem. Do the same trick again to expand using the series for $\log(1+x)$. Conclude.

Comment: Using the above, I calculated $$\frac{1}{\ln\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+81}-8\right)}\sim18x+\frac{5}{9}-\frac{538343}{78803442x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)$$ (assuming I did the laurent series expansions correctly by hand) which is slightly more information than you get from the limit alone. The number of terms necessary starts to explode since you have to expand multiple times (once for the series of $\sqrt{1+x}$, once for $\log(1+x)$, and once for the Laurent series for $\frac{1}{1-x}$), so even the $x^{-2}$ term doesn't seem nice to calculate...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Under $\frac1x\to t$, one has
$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \Bigl(\frac{1}{\ln\bigl(\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+81}-8\bigr)}-18x\Bigr)=\lim\limits_{t\to0} \frac{t-18\ln\bigl(\sqrt{t+81}-8\bigr)}{t\ln\bigl(\sqrt{t+81}-8\bigr)}$$
which is $\frac{0}{0}$ and so one can use L'Hospital's rule.

Answer (score 1):

let $y = \frac 1x$

This way we can take the limit as y approaches 0, which is often easier to work with.

$(a^2 + y)^\frac 12 = a + \frac {1}{2a} y - \frac {1}{8a^3} y^2 + \cdots\\
(81+ y)^\frac 12 = 9+\frac {1}{18}y - \frac {1}{18^3}y^2 + \cdots\\
(81+ y)^\frac 12 - 8 = 1+\frac {1}{18}y - \frac {1}{18^3}y^2 + \cdots$

$\ln (1 + a) = a - \frac {a^2}{2} + \cdots\\
\ln (1+\frac {1}{18}y - \frac {1}{18^3}y^2+\cdots) = \frac {1}{18}y - \frac {1}{18^3}y^2-\frac {1}{2\cdot 18^2}y^2 + \cdots\\
\ln (1+\frac {1}{18}y - \frac {1}{18^3}y^2) = \frac {1}{18}y - \frac {10}{18^3}y^2 + \cdots$

$\frac {1}{\frac {1}{18}y - \frac {10}{18^3}y^2 + \cdots} - \frac {18}{y}\\
\frac {18^3}{y(18^2 + 10y + \cdots} - \frac {18}{y}\\
\frac {18^3 - 18^3 + 180y + \cdots}{y(18^2 - 10y + \cdots)}\\
\lim_\limits{y\to 0} \frac {1}{\ln (\sqrt {81 + y} - 8)} - \frac {18}{y} = \frac {5}{9}$

Comment: That's interesting approach! Thanks for explaining